# exec: 23: python: not found error?

Tags: python, android

im trying to build android from source on ubuntu 10.04. when i enter the repo command:

repo init -u git://android.git.kernel.org/platform/manifest.git -b eclair

it get this error back

exec: 23: python: not found

any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

You should check your python instalation as the repo command is an python script made by Google to interact with git repositories.

If you do have python installed it is possible that it is not in your shell path or you are using a diferent version than required by repo, ie. you have version 3 while repo requires version 2.5 (just an example, I'm not sure what version repo uses).

Comment: could you provide more info on how to check my python installation?

Comment: just open a shell and type "python --version" would do.